# Creating gallery based on pictures taken by Xam.Plugin.Media

Tags: c#, plugins, xamarin.forms, gallery, media

Im kind of new in Xamarin.forms and c# and App Development.
Currently I'm working on an App which takes pictures and then u can send them to a server so you can check them on a WebApp. I'm Working with Xamarin.Forms.

The thing is that I'm getting crazy trying **to create a Gallery with the pictures you take**. Kind of like showing the pictures that are saved in the System-Folder (Not the default-gallery of the device) in a "infinite Scrollview + 2x2 Grid" way.

I would really really appreciate if someone can point me on the right direction or give me a hint, link, example, whatever! ><

[This is how the App looks like right now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJebU.png)

[And this is my goal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RLuf.png)

My XAML really simple:

```
 <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout
                Margin="20">

                <Image
                    x:Name="PhotoImage" />

                <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal" >

                    <Button 
                        x:Name="CameraButton"
                        BackgroundColor="#95c241"
                        Text="Foto aufnehmen"
                        TextColor="White"
                        Clicked="CameraButton_Clicked"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        />

                    <!--<Button
                        x:Name="selectimagebutton"
                        BackgroundColor="#4ab8ae"
                        Clicked="selectimagebutton_clicked"
                        Text="aus der gallerie"
                        TextColor="white"
                        HorizontalOptions="endandexpand" 

                        />-->

                    <Button
                        x:Name="SyncButton"
                        BackgroundColor="#95c241"
                        Clicked="SyncButton_Clicked"
                        Text="Synchronisierung"
                        TextColor="White"
                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />

                </StackLayout>
```

My MainPage.xampl.cs. I twitched it a lot and dont know if it might be helpfull for you:

```
//Camera Logic
    public async Task<bool> CheckPhotoPermissionsAsync()
    {
        var cameraStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
        var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

        if (cameraStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Camera, Permission.Storage });
            cameraStatus = results[Permission.Camera];
            storageStatus = results[Permission.Storage];
        }

        return cameraStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted || storageStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted;
    }

        private async void CameraButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Toma la foto y la muestra directamente en la pagina
        //Macht ein Foto und zeigt es auf diese Seite

        bool photoPermissions = await CheckPhotoPermissionsAsync();

        if (!photoPermissions)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Achtung!", "Damit die App einwandfrei läuft, mussen Sie den Zulassungen zustimmen", "ok");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                //If camera option not available
                //Falls das Handy keine Kamera hat
                await DisplayAlert("Hmmm...!", "Das Gerät hat kein Zugriff auf die Kamera...", "ok");
                return;
            }

            var mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = false,
                //Directory = "FotoApp_Folder",
                Name = fileName(),

                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Custom,

                //SaveMetaData = false,

                //Nurr bei PhotoSize.Custom
                CustomPhotoSize = 20,
                CompressionQuality = 70,

                //Only for iOS
                AllowCropping = true

            });

            //var mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            //{
            //    SaveToAlbum = false,
            //});

            //await saveScaleAsync(mediaFile);
            //Debug.WriteLine("It work baby! The mediaFile is: " + mediaFile);

            await saveMediaFile(mediaFile);

            var x = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = mediaFile.GetStream();
                //mediaFile.Dispose();
                return stream;                                     

            });

            Debug.WriteLine("It works baby! The mediaFile is: " + mediaFile);

            //await ToBase64(mediaFile);

        }
    }

    private async Task saveMediaFile(MediaFile mediaFile)
    {
        if (mediaFile == null)
        {
            //Falls kein Bild vorhanden ist
            await DisplayAlert("Ups!", "Es gibt kein Bild vorhanden", "ok");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var xxx = mediaFile.Path;

            //PhotoTable ist eine Klasse in diesem Fall , die die Attribute vom DB hat.
            var s = new PhotoTable
            {
                Filename = mediaFile.Path,
                Created_At = DateTime.Now,
                Sync_At = null
            };

            await HelperDB.Instance.conn.InsertAsync(s);
            PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.GetStream());

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            //Falls was nicht mit dem DB klappt....
            await DisplayAlert("Ups!", "Bitte versuchen Sie das nochmal. Es gab ein problem mit dem DB" + ee.ToString(), "ok");
        }

        updateText();

    }

    public string fileName()
    {
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

        string fileName = $"IMAGE_{d.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")}_.jpg";

        return fileName;
    }
```

Comment: if you want to display a 2x2 grid of images, then use a Grid for your image layout

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I know approximately how the Grid layout goes. The problem that I have is actually creating a gallery with the images previousely taken throw this "FromStream()" method, which I use to show the picture I choose to take in a simple "ImageView", like you can see in the pictures I uploaded

Comment: based on your post it's really difficult to determine what the specific problem you're having is.  What specific task do you need to do that you don't understand how to do, or can't get to work?  "Display images in a gallery" is NOT a specific task - it's too broad and potentially has dozens of sub-tasks.